# Mount external Hard Drive with /etc/fstab on ubuntu 14.04 problems

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd, automount, plex

I have been stuck for about two days trying to get this to work properly. I have done all of the following with still no luck.

I'm trying to auto permanently mount to a 2 TB Seagate Central that is on my network, using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop and I updated all `cifs` before starting.

I added the following line to `/etc/fstab` as root:

> ```
> #Mapping network drive
> //Ip-address/media/videos  /media/storage cifs username=username,password=password,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntl
> ```

I also swapped out the ip-address for its name as well. Since I know this is not the most secure way, but I'm the only one using this Ubuntu-Desktop
also tried the credentials document method without luck.

In the terminal:

```
sudo mount -a

mount error(22): Invaild argument
refer to mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

After seeing that I tried the following:

```
sudo mount.cifs //Seagate-XXXXX/Media/videos /media/storage
```

I was then promoted for the password to the network storage and enter in correctly:

```
Error:
mount error(115): operation now in progress  
Refer to mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I got it to work one time, but i had to reinstall Ubuntu after that, and can't seem to get it back working.

I've looked up many different videos and forums and I'm doing this so I can set up my Plex server to see my media folder on a external hard drive.

I have red and watched the following links/videos to no avail [Please Help!]:

- [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)
- [Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux](https://support.plex.tv/hc/en-us/articles/200288606-Mounting-NTFS-Drives-on-Linux)
- [Mounting network drive in fstab Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218634)
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBPxgVxOvTQ

Answer (score 2):

The first error you got is because there is no such thing as `sec=ntl`. The available options are (from `man mount.cifs`):

> sec=
>
> Security mode. Allowed values are:
>
> - none - attempt to connection as a null user (no name)
> - krb5 - Use Kerberos version 5 authentication
> - krb5i - Use Kerberos authentication and forcibly enable packet
>        signing
> - ntlm - Use NTLM password hashing
> - ntlmi - Use NTLM password hashing and force packet signing
> - ntlmv2 - Use NTLMv2 password hashing
> - ntlmv2i - Use NTLMv2 password hashing and force packet signing
> - ntlmssp - Use NTLMv2 password hashing encapsulated in Raw
>        NTLMSSP message
> - ntlmsspi - Use NTLMv2 password hashing encapsulated in Raw
>        NTLMSSP message, and force packet signing

So, the first approach (using the `fstab`) might work if you use one of the above. Presumably, you wanted `sec=ntlm`.

---

As for the `115` error, I found [this very nice guide](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-926114.html) on the Gentoo forums that I suggest you read. Basically, it suggests adding a line like this to your `/etc/hosts` file (change `192.168.1.12` to the IP of your drive):

```
192.168.1.12    Seagate-XXXXX
```

Once that's done, you should be able to use `Seagate-XXXXX` instead of the IP to connect. The page provides some other troubleshooting tips (including using `smbtree` to make sure that the share is actually available). I really suggesty you read it.

Comment: What is the Link to that page?

Comment: @user280186 ouch, sorry, I forgot it. [Here you go](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-926114.html) and I also added it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the mount command to /etc/rc.local ?  /etc/rc.local is a file that is executed by root at boot time and normally doesn't do anything.  However you can edit it and add your own stuff.  Just make sure that you move the "exit 0" command that's already in there down below the commands you want it to execute.

That's how I auto-mount my USB connected external at boot.  Just make a mount point with:

sudo mkdir /mnt/foo

Where foo is whatever name you want to give it.  Then edit /etc/rc.local and add the mount command on a line anywhere above the exit command.  Just be aware that when mounted this way, most desktop environments in my experience no longer detect it as an external device, so you won't have the fancy little icon, you'll actually have to navigate to and bookmark /mnt/foo in order to browse the drive.

I started auto-mounting mine with rc.local after having all sorts of issues editing fstab.  Hope this helps, :-)

Edit:

Here are the entire contents of my rc.local file.  I just thought I would share so you can see what I did.  Prior to saving your rc.local and rebooting though, make sure that whatever mount point you specify in the mount command has actually been created.  Also there is no need to add "sudo" to commands here, they are executed by the root user.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#Mounts Storage
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/Storage

exit 0
```

Comment: Yeah i tried, but no luck either

Answer (score 0):

thank you for answer so quick.

SO for the first error i was missing the m so  my code looks like this

```
#Mapping network drive
//Ip-address/media/videos/media/storage cifs username=username,password=password,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

so now when i run

```
sudo mount -a
mount error(115): operation now in progress  
Refer to mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

then when i try

```
sudo mount.cifs //Seagate-XXXXX/Media/videos /media/storage --verbose 
Password for root@//Segate-XXXX/Media/videos:
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=198.105.251.210,unc=\\SEAGATE-XXXXX\Media,user=root,prefixpath=videos,pass=*******
mount error(115): Operation now in progress
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I know it can see the drive

```
user@myserver: ~$ smbtree -b -N
WORKGROUP
        \\SEAGATE-XXXXX                      Seagate Centeral Shared Storage
        \\XXXXXXX-TIME-CA                    XXXXXX's Time Capsule
        \\MYSERVER                           myserver server (Samba, Ubuntu)
                 \\MYSERVER\IPC$             IPC service (myserver server (Samba, Ubuntu))
                 \\MYSERVER\print$           Printer Drivers
```

SO it sees my network drive, but this is also a password protected drive so i didnt expect to see the folders for USER and PUBLIC

SO now I'm even more lost?
ANy SUggestion??

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mount -t cifs '//Seagate-XXXXX/Media/videos' //media/storage -o username=username,password=password,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

works for me with a goflex seagate as well as 2 centrals but I have added to host file for ips

Simple things:

Can you log into the nas on its web interface with your username and password if so not that

```
//Seagate-XXXXX/Media/videos
```

are you sure this is correct path name because for me anything in private directory is

```
//Seagate-XXXXX/username/Media/videos
```

Does your ubuntu user have full access to `//media/storage` directory?

Last not least remember file and directory mode ubuntu seems to be picky about these where crunchbang wasnt

I have done the `/etc/rc.local` thing only I call a script `nas.sh` which is basically an executable text file with the mount comand.

```
#!/bin/bash
mount -t cifs '//Seagate-XXXXX/Media/videos' //media/storage -o username=username,password=password,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```